# Unable to publish a Open Graph Action and I receive a weird response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My code used to work, but now I am not able to publish any actions. Everything seems to be in order but the response I get from Facebook is a JSON list of the last 25 actions I took. I know my action isn't published because I'm watching it live in a browser. I'm also trying to post these actions with a browser.

Here is my code:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/NAMESPACE:ACTION?OBJECT=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html&access_token=TOKEN`

The response is 25 of these:

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "id": ""****"",
     "from": {
        "id": ""****"",
        "name": "****"
     },
     "start_time": "2012-05-05T04:56:38+0000",
     "end_time": "2012-05-05T04:56:38+0000",
     "publish_time": "2012-05-05T04:56:38+0000",
     "application": {
        "id": ""****"",
        "name": ""****"
     },
     "data": {
        "website": {
           "id": ""****"",
           "url": "****",
           "type": "website",
           "title": "****"
        }
     },
     "likes": {
        "count": 0
     },
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  },
```

of course the **** are actual values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do HTTP POST for actions in a browser, only HTTP GET, which is why you receive the list of previous actions.

Please use cURL or the Graph API Explorer to accomplish creating an action.

Comment: indeed! for some reason I thought this worked before. Anyways - I used my Gap app to do the posts and it worked perfectly. Thank you!